# Linear Algebra Challenge in Physics.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In physics, we denote $B^\dagger$ as $B$'s Hermitian i.e. $B^\dagger=(B^T)^*=(B^*)^T$, where $^*$ is taking complex conjugate of elements in the matrices.

Here is my question:

> Assume that $B$ and $B^\dagger$ are linear map on a complex vector space(or their elements are complex numbers), in short they are complex valued matrices, and they obey relation $[B,\,B^\dagger]=BB^\dagger-B^\dagger B=I$, where $I$ is identity matrix. Assume $B$ has an eigen-vector (column vector) $x$ which obeys $Bx=0$, and $x^\dagger x=1$. For the second condition, we say $x$ is normalized.
>
> $a)$ Calculate $x^\dagger B^n(B^\dagger)^n x$
> $b)$ Proof that vector $y=e^{zB^\dagger}x=(I+zB^\dagger+\frac{z^2(B^\dagger)^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3(B^\dagger)^3}{3!}+\cdots)x$ is also an eigenvector of $B$. Where the last equality is doing Taylor's expansion, and $z$ is a complex number.
> $c)$ Calculate $y_1^\dagger y_2$, where $y_1$ and $y_2$ have different complex numbers.

My attempt is to expand the middle term of $B^n(B^\dagger)^n$, which looks like $\cdots BBB^\dagger B^\dagger\cdots$, by using $BB^\dagger=I+B^\dagger B$. However, one can find that these methods could have an enormous work when the powers go to 4.

From my calculation, $x^\dagger B(B^\dagger) x=1$; $x^\dagger B^2(B^\dagger)^2 x=2$; $x^\dagger B^3(B^\dagger)^3 x=6$, and I guess power of n term can have $n!$. However, I cannot even find a recursive relation...

Aside: Vectors in $b)$ is important in quantum computing. 
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, it is my typo

Comment: There is something missing here. The identity can never be a commutator: if you take trace on the equality $AB-BA=I$, you get $0$ on the left and $n$ on the right.

Comment: You just asked a good question. The reason is that This $B$  is infinite dimension "matrix" (in math, matrix is defined to be finite, since it is in finite group). Hence, there is no way to define the usual concept of trace on the infinite dimension matrices. However, their other properties still follow from their finite brother. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a) and (b), you can use this useful fact: If $p(t)$ is a polynomial (or a power series), then $Bp(B^\dagger) - p(B^\dagger)B = p'(B^\dagger)$. (You can show it for $p(t) = t^n$ by induction on $n$, and then extend linearly.)

So for (a), you can repeatedly use $B(B^\dagger)^n = (B^\dagger)^nB + n(B^\dagger)^{n-1}$ to find the result.

For (b), consider $p(t) = e^{zt}$.

For (c), I assume you mean $y_1$ and $y_2$ are eigenvectors with different eigenvalues? Then the result is a general fact about Hermitian operators.

Comment: I have never seen this relation before, I will give a try. Thanks. However I am hoping someone who can give a more direct way to show this.

Comment: Well, you could just prove $B(B^\dagger)^n - (B^\dagger)^nB = n(B^\dagger)^{n-1}$ by induction and use that result directly. But thinking about it in terms of derivatives makes it easier to remember IMHO :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. This result follows from arithmetic of Lie bracket quickly. I think this solution could be the most direct one. But I still wanna see whether there are any other easy, brilliant solution :).